# Como inserir ícones em JSF?

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, xhtml

Em um formulário de cadastro tenho de inserir ícones de edição e remoção em um formulário feito em JSF.

```xml
<h:commandLink action="#{clienteController.editar}">Editar
```

<kbd>[image: imagem-exemplo]</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode estar utilizando o [`commandLink`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/commandLink.html) juntamente com o [`graphicImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/graphicImage.html), exemplo:

```xml
<h:commandLink action="#{clienteController.editar}">
    <h:graphicImage value="img/imagem.png" />
</h:commandLink>
```